# Tax deduct rental property expenses in future

Tags: tax-deduction, investing, australia, rental-property

I'm an australian doing postgrad in australia, and my current government awarded income is tax-exempted.

I would like to know if in a couple of years when I start working, I can tax-deduct the currently tax-deductible expenses I've been paying on some rental property I lease out.

Were my current income taxable, I'd be able to deduct the expenses on the rental property now; however, I have nothing against which I can tax deduct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deduct your rental property expenses against your rental property income. If your rental property expenses are greater than your total rental property income, then you can deduct the excess expenses from income from other sources during the same income year.

If you do not have any other taxable income for the income year and your rental expenses are more than your rental income, then you will end up with a Tax Loss for that income year, which then can be carried forward against taxable income you earn in future income years.